# jquery.validate failing with "a is null"

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that I have been building, and I am trying to validate a single field.  So, I decided that I would introduce jQuery.validate to my app so if I need to do more validation in the future, I will have the plugin included.

Doing some testing, I added:

```
jQuery("#NextFollowUpDateTimePicker").rules("add", {
  minlength: 2
});
```

My input ID is "NextFollowUpDateTimePicker", and I haven't even tried to validate yet, but am just trying to add the rule.  When I inspect the console with Firebug I get the following error:

```
a is null
```

This is being thrown from my jQuery file (1.5.1).  Has anybody else come across this?  I have all kinds of other JS files included, so I am guessing it is some kind of conflict, but I am not really sure how to debug this.

Thanks in advance!
-Matt

Comment: What is the version of MVC do you use ? MVC comes with unobstrusive validation out of the box. [See doc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

Comment: MVC3 ... I will check that out, however if I wanted to use jquery.validate (for whatever reason) I would still be hosed right now.

Comment: Well, the MVC3 validation uses the jQuery.validate plugin. It's fully integrated with model validation and DataAnnotations and it adds unobstrusive capabilities to the javascript validation mechanism (meaning the validation rules/messages are stored in html data attributes). Check the link I gave you, it's pretty complete.

Comment: This style of validation requires that the parent form is validated, that is, $("form").validate() is called first. Have you done that? I know nothing about ASP, but if you can use the class= style of validation, you may find it easier. Set your $("form").validate() statements, and then just put class="required" or class="minlength[2]" in the input box HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have called `$("#myForm").validate();` before adding any rules. Also if you are adding dynamic inputs to validate, make sure that you add them to the DOM before adding the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the below code is going to help someone, as I did encountered inappropriate behavior when i called the JQuery validator upon click of submit button to validate the fields and perform a AJAX call. The validation was not working as expected upon multiple submissions until i added the below statement. Looks like the DOM needs to be reset upon form submission in order to avoid any browser refresh to make the validation work as expected.

`$.data($(id)[0], 'validator', null);`

**JSP** file showing the input type submit

```
<input type="submit" id="label.login.button" name="label.login.button"
       value="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-block">
```

**JavaScript** performing the validation and processing the form submission

```
 /**
 * 
 * @author dinesh.lomte
 */

/**
 * 
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    reset('#loginForm');
    // Validating the login form on submit  
    validateLoginForm();
});

/**
 * 
 * @param id
 * @returns
 */
function reset(id) {    
    $.data($(id)[0], 'validator', null);
}

/**
 * 
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function validateLoginForm() {
    // Validating the login form
    $('#loginForm').validate({
        rules: {
            userId:     {
                required:   true,
                userId:     true
            },
            password:   'required'
        },
        messages: {
            userId: {
                required: function() {
                    // Message: Please enter User ID.
                    return $.i18n('business.message.00001');
                },
                userId: function() {
                    // Message: Invalid character(s) found. Please enter valid characters.
                    return $.i18n('business.message.00003');
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: function() {
                    // Message: Please enter Password.
                    return $.i18n('business.message.00002');
                }
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // Processing the login request
            processLoginRequest();
        }
    });
    return false;
}

/**
 * 
 * @returns
 */
function processLoginRequest() {
    // Building the json instance to process login request
    var formData = {'userId':$('#userId').val(),
                    'password':$('#password').val(),
                    'language':$('#language').val()
                    };
    $.ajax({
        type        :'POST',
        contentType :'application/json',
        url         :getContextPath() + '/login',
        data        :JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType    :'json',
        beforeSend  :function() {
            $('#pleaseWaitModal').modal();
        },
        complete    :function() {
            $('#pleaseWaitModal').modal('hide'); 
        },
        success     :function(data) {
            // Validating ui message(s) for display
            if(hasUiMessages(JSON.stringify(data))) {
                return;
            }
            createHomeControllerForm(data);
            toggleComponents(true);
        },
        error       :function(exception) {
            // Message: Failed to process your request due to system 
            //          error. Please contact your system administrator.
            showI18nMessage('error', 'business.message.00005');
            toggleComponents(false);
        }
    });
}
```